# My login form is always saying that login credentials is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

My login form is always saying that credentials are incorrect. The form was working before I changed it to use either username or email. Not sure whats wrong with my code.

/****************User login functions ********************/

```
function login_user($email, $username, $password, $remember) {


    $sql = "SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email = '".escape($email)." || username = ".escape($username)."' AND active = 1";

    $result = query($sql);

    if(row_count($result) == 1) {

        $row = fetch_array($result);

        $db_password = $row['password'];


        if(md5($password) === $db_password) {

            if($remember == "on") {

                setcookie('email', $email, time() + 86400);

            }


            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


            return true;

        } else {


            return false;
        }









        return true;

    } else {


        return false;



    }



} // end of function
```

/****************logged in function ********************/

```
function logged_in(){

if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email'])){


    return true;

} else {


    return false;
}



}
```

Im not sure if anyone can help me sort this out

Comment: dont use md5, use something else. md5 is simply **one way**

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. I'm not sure if you're using PDO or Mysqli, but escaping your inputs is NOT secure. Look into how to properly secure your queries with [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will also eliminate a whole host of quoting issues.

Comment: Abdulla: MD5 shouldn't be used - but not because it's a one way hash - because it's way (way) too easy (fast) to calculate. OP: you should fix that and start using prepared/parameterized queries because people will only nag you about that before answering anything (like they should)

Comment: Your query is wrong `email = 'x@example.com || username = username'`, also what is row_count and fetch_array?

Comment: I used md5 previously and it worked. Its just when i added  the  email = '".escape($email)." || username = ".escape($username)."'  part, it stopped working

Comment: Parameterized queries would fix the problem here, mostly because the SQL is wrong (and at least partially tied to the incorrect quoting used).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I used the row_count and fetch_array because i was following a tutorial on udemy on how to create the form.     ' email = 'x@example.com || username = username' ' will this select the email from the database and tie it to the password

Comment: @LaveshPillay Better ask for your money back. I bet its using `mysql_*` based functions. Ditch it and find a better learning resource.

Comment: im not really going to use this form for much. for now its just to enhance my php knowledge. I will try your solution and see how it goes @LawrenceCherone

Comment: your logged_in function could look like this return isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email']);

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: If you want to know how uselessly weak MD5 passwords are, run a web search for "ec85070aa70e598eda72cbe82d99fabc". Even if you can't find a match there, [Hashcat](http://hashcat.net) can crack simple passwords instantly, harder ones in hours.

Answer (score 0):

I should add 2 single quotes in your SELECT

```
function login_user($email, $username, $password, $remember) {

$sql = "SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email = '".escape($email)."' 
|| username = '".escape($username)."' AND active = 1";
```